# Подскажите в чем ошибка? В консоле: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

```
const deadline = '2020-11-10';

 function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
     const t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date()),
           days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
           hours = Math.floor((t / (1000* 60 * 60) % 24)),
           minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60),
           seconsd = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);

        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconsd': seconsd
        };
 }

 function getZero(num) {
    if(num >= 0 && num < 10) {
        return `0${num}`;
    } else {
        return num;
    }
 }

 function setClock(selector, endtime) {
    const timer = document.querySelector(selector),
          days = timer.querySelector('#days'),
          hours = timer.querySelector('#hours'),
          minutes = timer.querySelector('#minutes'),
          seconsd = timer.querySelector('#seconsd'),
          timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

    updateClock();

function updateClock() {
    const t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        days.innerHTML = getZero(t.days);
        hours.innerHTML = getZero(t.hours);
        minutes.innerHTML = getZero(t.minutes);
        seconsd.innerHTML = getZero(t.seconsd);


        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
        }
    }
 }
 setClock('.timer', deadline);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.seconsd` - это так и задумывалось? :)

причем по всему коду - CopyPaste - это зло

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!